# Cursor cannot be displayed when inputting long characters In Edit Text

Tags: android

I am using custom cursor "/" like image  in Edit  text but entering the long text.The cursor will invisible at the end of the edit text i added some padding but no use please suggest a solution for this.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:ems="10"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:layout_marginTop="77dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
     android:padding="4dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor" 
    android:/>

Thanks
Rahul
```